# Code after ProgressDialog (Android) gets executed before the ProgressDialog's timer runs out

Tags: android, progressdialog

When I click a button `BUTTON`, I'm showing a ProgressDialog popup, which shows the round circling progress meter thing. Now that's supposed to run for N seconds, and after that, there's some code which executes only after the temporarily created ProgressDialog instance vanishes (when N seconds are up). The code shows some text in a TextView, and the text changes on every click of `BUTTON`, and an image which should change too. But the change is to be visible only after the ProgressDialog has ended

But the problem is, as soon as I click  `BUTTON`, the text already changes, and the ProgressDialog circling dialog plays on for N seconds, which is not supposed to happen - the text should change only after the ProgressDialog finished circling for its N seconds, and the app `View` is back in focus, and the text gets changed then.

Here's the code:

```
BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

    //Choosing MESXs type to show =================================
                if(mTSFlag==1)
                    mTS=holA;
                else
                    mTS=holB;

    // ProgressDialog =================================
                final ProgressDialog progressRing=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait..", "This takes time..", true);
                        progressRing.setCancelable(false);
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {  
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    try
                                    {
                                          Thread.sleep(3000);
                                    }catch(Exception e){}
                                    progressRing.dismiss();
                              }
                        }).start();


                //Image choosing logic ================================= 
                imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

                if(pTOGGLE)
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.IMG_XXT);
                else
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.IMG_XYT);

                wIHM_result.setText(mTS);

            }
        });
```

The problem is, that it's as if the `Image Logic` part (marked by a header comment), is run before the `ProgressDialgo` part of the code. The appropriate image shows up, the text is changed, I can see all that in the dimmed app screen while the ProgressDialog is making it's progress to the end of N seconds.

I want it to show the changed image and text (objects here in code - imageView and wIHM respectively) after the Progress Dialog circling thing has finished circling and the focus is back on the app's view.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsynTask class.
Write the button click in it and use progress Dialog in AsynTask..

AsynTask have method like initBackground() , preExecute() , postExecute() ..

Start the progress Dialog in preExecute... write the logic in initBackground with ending the logic last line with ProgressDialog.dismiss(); and write the textchange code and imagechange logic in postExecute();

```
BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

          public void onClick(View v)  {
               new ABC.Execute();
            }
        });
public class ABC extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    ProgressDialog downloadProgressDialog =new ProgressDialog(Accounts.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Set your text and image object here....

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        downloadProgressDialog.setMessage("Message");
            downloadProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            downloadProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
    {

        //Write your code here......
        downloadProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use the AsyncTask to do. If you want to fix the issue based on your code, you should do like these:

```
BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

    //Choosing MESXs type to show =================================
    if(mTSFlag==1)
        mTS=holA;
    else
        mTS=holB;

    // ProgressDialog =================================
    final ProgressDialog progressRing=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait..", "This takes time..", true);
    progressRing.setCancelable(false);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
               Thread.sleep(3000);

               //Don't run your UI method in non-Ui thread.
               //move progressRing.dismiss() to runOnUiThread();
               yourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       progressRing.dismiss();

                       //Image choosing logic ================================= 
                       imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

                       if(pTOGGLE)
                           imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.IMG_XXT);
                       else
                           imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.IMG_XYT);

                       wIHM_result.setText(mTS);
                   }
               }catch(Exception e){
               }
           }
       }).start();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 progressRing.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Image choosing logic codes should be here for processing after dialog showed
    }
 });
```

`setOnShowListener` sets a listener to be invoked when the dialog is shown

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code of what it does, this will also help future visitors.